# UTF-8 Normalization Logstash to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

The data standards state that all data coming into our ES Index must be UTF-8. I am looking for a component of logstash that will allow me to apply a UTF-8 filter of some kind to normalize the data stream.

Comment: What kind of inputs do you have? Most of the default codecs used in inputs have a default UTF8 charset.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have control over the inputs.

Comment: I meant Logstash input plugins.

Comment: udp {
        port => 514
        type => syslog
         codec => plain {
                 charset => "ISO-8859-1"
        }
      }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you're getting ISO data via UDP (which you can't change) and you want to somehow translate that to UTF8.

Well, just know that Logstash will already transform your input to UTF-8, you're just telling it that you're getting some ISO-encoded content via `udp`, but Logstash will handle everything downstream in UTF-8.

You can check this thread for more information: https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1047